# Analyze the evolution of a population over time

Tags: r, dplyr

Each day I have a new csv file with ids and some variables. The ids can be differents over the days. I would like to take the IDs of one day and follow how a variable evolves over the time.

My goal is to create area plot like this : [image]

For example I take all the ids the 31 march, each day I make a join with thoses ids, and I make a count group by the var "Code". If there is missing ids (Ids here the 31 march but not day D) their code become "NA" to show how many IDs I "lose" over time. I hope i'm clear enough.

Here is how I calculate this king of plot : (my real datas are like `li` and not `datas`)

```
library(plyr)
library(dplyr)

datas <- data.frame(id1 = c("x", "y", "x", "y", "z", "x", "z"), 
                    id2 = c("x2", "y2", "x2", "y2", "z2", "x2", "z2"), 
                    code = c("code1", "code2", "code1", "code2", "code2", "code1", "code2"),
                    var = runif(7),
                    date = do.call(c, mapply(rep, seq(Sys.Date() - 2, Sys.Date(), by = 1), c(2, 3, 2))))

li <- split(datas, datas$date)

dateStart <- Sys.Date() - 2
dateEnd <- Sys.Date()
# A "filter" if I want to start with another date than the date min or end with another date than the max date
li <- li[as.Date(names(li)) >= dateStart & as.Date(names(li)) <= dateEnd]

dfCounts <- ldply(li, function(x) 
  left_join(li[[1]], x, by = c("id1", "id2")) %>% 
    group_by(code.y) %>% 
    count(code = code.y) %>% 
    mutate(freq = n / sum(n), 
           code = ifelse(is.na(code), "NA", code))), 
  .id = "date")

> dfCounts
date code n freq
1 2015-07-04    1 1  0.5
2 2015-07-04    2 1  0.5
3 2015-07-05    1 1  0.5
4 2015-07-05    2 1  0.5
5 2015-07-06    1 1  0.5
6 2015-07-06   NA 1  0.5

dfCounts %>% 
  ggplot(aes(date, freq)) + 
  geom_area(aes(fill = code), position = "stack")
# I have no idea why in this example, nothing is shown in the plot, but it works on my real datas
```

So it works, but if I want to observe a longer period, I have to join over many days (files) and it can be slow. Do you have any ideas to do the same things without joins, using the binded datas (the object datas and not li) with dplyr or data.table ?

In your opinion, which approach is better ?

Thanks !
(Sorry for the title I couldn't find better...)

Comment: You may want to look into using `data.table` and `rbindlist()`.  `data.table` by-reference operations are more efficient than the base operations e.g., `rbind()` since they do not rewrite the entire data set.

Comment: I am not able to reproduce your results.  I keep getting an error `Error in count(., code) : object 'code' not found` after both instances of `%>% group_by(code) %>%   count(code)`.

Comment: Why tag data.table when you have not tried anything using it?

Comment: Well, I try to work on the dataframe with either dplyr or data.table, and what I have tried is not worth to be shown. So I justed posted what I've achieve which is with dplyr and tagged data.table because I think it could be a great solution. Anyway, I delete the tag if this is a misuse of it...

Comment: Not sure how you'd work on a data.frame <with> data.table. These tags (dplyr/data.table) are very specific to bugs, questions or better solutions using those packages, and not for questions where one thinks there might be a better solution using that package. Seems to be a common misconception though. Thanks for removing the tag.